# Setting seaborn theme causes bug in Dataframe.plt.bar() results

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have generated a plot using the following code:

```
year_sum = ct.sum(axis=1)
month_sum = ct.sum(axis=0)
month_avg = ct.mean(axis=0)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 5))
plot_style = {'marker': 'o', 'color': 'b', 'ms': 10, 'mec': 'b', 'mfc': 'r', 'lw':2}
custom_legend = [Line2D([0], [0], **plot_style),
                 Line2D([0], [0], lw=2, color='black')]

# Axes 0: Lineplot and regression of number of storms per year
sns.lineplot(y=year_sum, x=year_sum.index, ax=axes[0])
sns.regplot(y=year_sum, x=year_sum.index, ax=axes[0], ci=0)

# Axes 1: frequency plot of number of storms per month
month_avg.plot(ax=axes[1],  linestyle='--', **plot_style)
ct.T.plot.bar(legend=None, ax=axes[1], color='black')

axes[0].set_ylabel("Total Recorded Storms")
axes[1].set_ylabel("# of Recorded Storms")
axes[1].set_xticks(np.arange(1, 13))
axes[1].legend(custom_legend, ['Avg Monthly Storms', 'Years'])
```

[image]

However, I want to increase the aesthetics of the plot by using `sns.set_theme(style='whitegrid')`. When I do so, this is the result:

[image]

No amount of changing the color argument of the barplot fixes this. Whereas I have full control over the color before using `sns.set_theme()` call.

### Sample data to run my code with:

You may use this subset of my crosstable for the `ct` to make the code run:

```
        1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
                                                
1851    0   0   0   0   0   1   2   1   1   1   0   0
1852    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   3   1   0   0
1853    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   4   1   0   0
1854    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   2   1   0   0
1855    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   1   0   0   0
```

Is this a bug I can work around? If so, how?

Comment: have you tried restarting your kernel ? I've tried your sample code with both `sns.set_style("whitegrid")` or `sns.set_theme(style='whitegrid')` and works

Comment: seaborn sets the edgecolor of patches to white. you are drawing very thin bars with thick edges; what's happening is you're only "seeing" the edges (but then not exactly seeing them, because they are drawn in white).

Comment: @mwaskom Thank you, setting `edgecolor='black'` did the trick nicely.